# Ceiling function within verbatim in latex

Tags: verbatim

I am preparing a latex document. Inside the body of a function I need to use the ceiling function. How will I use the ceiling function inside verbatim?

```
\begin{verbatim}

Method a(b)

    .
    .
    .

  return a(ceiling of sqrt(b));

\end{verbatim}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to write ceiling inside verbatim?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) provides a stepping stone to mix regular math with `verbatim` content. Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb
\newcommand{\mesc}[1]{$#1$}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
Method \mesc{a(b)}
    .
    .
    .
return \mesc{a(\lceil\sqrt{b}\rceil)};
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

You can, of course, also try using [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings), which provides the `mathescape` key; yielding similar results as above.