# Underscore vs. subscript in new command with fancyvrb

Tags: math-mode, verbatim

I'm using fancyvrb to have math in my verbatim environment as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103713/ceiling-function-within-verbatim-in-latex).

I use a math escape command like so:
`\newcommand{\m}[1]{$#1$}`

But underscores are not being type set as subscripts, they are showing up as underscores.

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
for \m{i = 1, 2, \dots n}:
    sample \m{x_i} from \m{P(X_i \vert \mathrm{Parents}(X_i))}
return \m{(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)}
\end{Verbatim}
```

[image]

How can I have subscripts using the `_` symbol? I think it is related to the definition of my new command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\m` definition is missing a bit:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\m][1]{\def\FV@Space{ }$#1$}
\makeatother
```

so that spaces are treated as usual in math (that is, ignored). But I'll add something more. You can exploit the fact that in verbatim mode the underscore is a printable character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\m}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\FV@Space{ }% spaces in math are ignored
  \mathcode`\_="8000 % _ is math active
  \do@@us % underscore is subscript
  $#1$%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\do@@us}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`\_ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sb
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
for \m{i = 1, 2, \dots n}:
    sample \m{x_i} from \m{P(X_i \mid \mathrm{Parents}(X_i))}
return \m{(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)}
this_is_verb
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to add codes as such in the Verbatim environment

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},codes={\catcode`$=3 \catcode`_=8}]
for \m{i=1,2,\dots,n}:
    sample \m{x_i} from \m{P(X_i\vert\mathrm{Parents}(X_i))}
return \m{(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)}
\end{Verbatim}
```

[image]

Comment: There's still the problem with spaces.

Comment: @egreg -- Observed and corrected accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If it may be ad hoc solution, the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\def\m#1{\global\catcode`\_=8$#1$}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
for \m{i = 1, 2, \dots n}:
    sample \m{x_i} from \m{P(X_i \vert \mathrm{Parents}(X_i))}
return \m{(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)}
\end{Verbatim}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Limitations:
1. One cannot use `_` as underscore inside `Verbatim` now.
2. Spacing in math mode is still strange.
3. Not tested for conflicts.

**Second version**
But why one had to choose? If we use the definition outside `Verbatim` and inject the results into it, we have both: math and verbatim (only two cases replaced):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\def\m#1{$#1$}
\def\AAA{ \m{i = 1, 2, \dots n}}
\def\BBB{\m{(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)}}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
for \m{i = 1, 2, \dots n}:
\AAA
    sample \m{x_i} from \m{P(X_i \vert \mathrm{Parents}(X_i))}
return \m{(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)}
\BBB
\end{Verbatim}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try having `_` in the *first* call of `\m`. It's hard to salvage something from this answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: @egreg The second version should be more efficient.